# What can of selector do I need to select for the presence of an ID and a class?

Tags: jquery

I would like to check for

```
#dialogOrder
```

and

```
.menu-mask
```

Is the following valid and is there an even easier shortcut ?

```
$("#dialogOrder").$(".menu-mask")
```

**Update**

I just realized I also need to select the element only if it is on a form with the class of menu. Sorry that this was not part of the original question. I hope someone can help me.

Comment: No, the above code is not valid

Comment: `$.fn.$ = $.fn.filter;` now it is.

Comment: There is clearly some question as to whether you're trying to find an element by ID that is also of class .menu-mask, or whether you're attempting to find multiple elements (both the one with an ID and any elements with the class. Care to clarify?

Comment: What I would really like to find is an element with: a) on a form with a class of "menu" b) item with a class of mask c) item with an id of dialogOrder. I think b and c could be interchanged. Thanks

Comment: The reason I have the class selector after the ID is because I am using the same javascript for more than one screen. One screen is the menu screen and the other is not. Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean you want to find an element with both ID `dialogOrder` and class `menu-mask`, simply use

```
jQuery("#dialogOrder.menu-mask")
```

If you want to know if this element exists in your document, try

```
if (jQuery("#dialogOrder.menu-mask").length > 0) {
    // element exists
}
```

Of course, adding the class selector is redundant as there should only be at most one element with any given ID attribute.

#### Update

To answer your comment, if you mean you want to find `dialogOrder` in

```
<form class="menu">
    <div id="dialogOrder">...</div>
</form>
```

You can use several methods

```
$("form.menu").find("#dialogOrder")
```

or

```
$("form.menu #dialogOrder")
```

Comment: How could I also add in a select to determine if this was on a form with class = menu?

Comment: Thanks Phil. Your answer is perfect.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for a tag that is both `#dialogOrder` AND `.menu-mask`, then you should use:

```
$("#dialogOrder.menu-mask")
```

Comment: Hello and thanks. Can you tell me if I also wanted to select only the #dialogOrder that appeared on a form with class = menu. How could I implement this with the above select?

Answer (score 1):

Try below

```
$("#dialogOrder.menu-mask");
```

Answer (score 1):

You chain the selectors:

```
$('#dialogOrder.menu-mask')
```

If you need to use a pre-existing selector, you can use the [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter) method:

```
$('.menu-mask').doStuff().filter('#dialogOrder').doMoreStuff();
```